# ModuleNotFoundError in Pycharm while importing from existing folder

Tags: python, import, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

I'm running a Python project in Pycharm structured as shown in the image and I'm trying to perform the following import in embedder_cmd.py :
`from Neural_PM.clustering.clustering_experiment import run_clustering`

I currently get the following error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Neural_PM'`

I've tried the solutions proposed in the previous answers but nothing seems to work for me.

Printing os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] currently shows my project path:
`C:\Users\Mark\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4`

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R17iJ.png)

Comment: That screenshot shows `pythonProject4`, not `pythonProject5`...

Comment: Give a look here [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `from ..clustering.clustering_experiment import run_clustering`. The two dots before clustering is to get out runners folder as your import statement is in embedder_cmd.py.
If that doesn't work and you get the "no known parent package" error, try without dots, like this `from clustering.clustering_experiment import run_clustering` and run `py -m <path to embedder_cmd.py>` at the top level of your project in terminal.
Something like this:
[image: test code]

Now look the result:
[image: test result]